# What's wrong with this code? (PHP+MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I'm learning PHP and I'm doing small PHP License system. This is my code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$conn = mysql_pconnect('localhost', 'xxx', 'xx');
$spp = mysql_select_db('licesing');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Active FROM `cms_license` WHERE `CustomerID` = '2' and `License_Key` = '123'");
if (mysql_num_rows($result)==1) {
  print('ok');
}
else {
  print('bad');
}
    ?>
```

Okay, so the problem is that when I'm query`in this thing I might get 2 responses 1st = "1" which means that it's active and "0" that it's disabled. This code kinda stucks at same response which is "ok" even when I will change Active status from 0 to 1. What should I do?
I arleady tried to replace == with = and > 0, but it doesn't work ^^

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, I have checked the connection before with this code and it's works.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and start `var_dump()`ing

Comment: Are you use your db isn't `licensing` instead of `licesing`? You may also want to try `if (mysql_num_rows($result) >0)`

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure I check it double.

Comment: Try removing the `$spp=` and do `mysql_select_db('licesing');` sometimes when there's an unused variable, SQL might act funny.

Comment: Also, if your columns are INT do `WHERE `CustomerID` = 2 and `License_Key` = 123` without the quotes around the `= '2'` and `= '123'` as in `= 2` and `= 123`

Comment: Yeah I removed quotas, it doesn't work also.

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine, having all columns set to VARCHAR. You either don't have the right columns selected (and/or DB/table), you made a typo, or they don't exists, or there's no data in them. Double check everything. Sometimes doing `License_Key` instead of `license_key` could be the problem, etc.

Comment: Have you tried to switch Active between 0 and 1? Did it give another output?

Comment: Yes I did all that. I pre-tested every possible scenario.

Comment: Make sure that `Active` and `CustomerID` and `License_Key` columns exist. If `Active` isn't a column yet, that will throw an error. Are you getting any errors at all?

Comment: No I dont get. Also I'm using this code for now:

$result = mysql_query("SELECT Active FROM `cms_license` WHERE `CustomerID` = 2");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) >0) {
  print('ok');
}
else {
  print('bad');
}

Double checked case sensitive letters - nothing ... also replaced values from int to varchar.

Comment: Column `CustomerID` does have an entry of `2` and column `License_Key` of `123`? They both have to exist.

Comment: And they do. They exist at same row.

Comment: **Make absolutely certain** that your `Active` column name in your DB table is not all in lowercase like `active`. If this is the case, your query will fail. I just *successfully* tested this theory now. This could also be the case for your two other column names.

Comment: So what is the status. Moments of silence mean one of two things. Either you figured out what was wrong and you are having fun with your new DB setup, or you're still trying to find out why.

Comment: I have figured it out - Database was correct from the start. mysql_num_rows function which I've used haven't work for me ((output was always same)), so I used  if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { if ($row['Active'] == 1) { } } this code instead of old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_num_rows($result)` returns the number of rows in the result, so yields 1 when it finds one row.

```
if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['Active'];
```

Here `$row['Active']` gives the value of the Active field. Is not that, which you would like to test?

```
    if ($row['Active'] == 1) {
        ...
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with OP's code. See [`my comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717726/whats-wrong-with-this-code-phpmysql#comment36452267_23717726) under OP's question to that effect.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I precised my understanding of the question.

Comment: I honestly don't know what's wrong at this point. I can't replicate the problem. I also used your suggestion and it always comes out false.

Comment: In order for `if ($row['Active'] == 1)` to work, the OP would need to have the number `1` (*or whatever number `2` or `123`*) in the Active column. I just figured what you wanted to show the OP.

Comment: Well I tested it out and it is working now. Finally. I needed to pair 2 lines of it, so it's like charm now :)